# Does cypress.zip install have the same functionality as NPM install

Tags: cypress

We're behind a firewall, so we cannot use NPM install.  However, we can use cypress.zip, but it seems that may only provide partial functionality.  Looking for a confirmation either way.

Installed but not sure how to compare functionality available.

Answer (score 0):

Either way of the installations works in the same way. That is why it's even suggested in the Cypress official [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as I've discovered actually there are differences (as the document suggests), and the biggest appears to be their Cloud cannot be used. Without npm, this also means supporting 3rd party modules may also not be available. Lastly, with direct, it is not installed in the cache, so running multiple projects can be a pain or you need to set the correct ENVs. Their statement "This (direct) download is only intended as a quick way to try out Cypress" suggests less capability IMO. I just wish the documentation was a little clearer.